# What is a composite application architecture in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Came around [Backbone Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) which says it provides composite application architecture.

What is a composite application architecture in JavaScript? and how does it help in building better Single Page Applications? (World is already full of so many design principles implemented in JS paradigm)

Does AngularJS provide composite application architecture? Why do I need this in JavaScript?

Comment: It's SOA term, AFAIK. Which means (for me) that there is a pretty high level of mapping/matching between your REST resources and your presentation. I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (which may not be correct!) is that it is to do with the composite pattern, which is essentially about trees, nodes and leaf nodes, and being able to work with them not knowing whether you have a leaf node or a branch node.

Marionette allows you to very easily write views composed from other views, applications composed of modules, and encourages reuse of components.

For example, let's say I want to display a view in a region. I can easily display this view by calling `myRegion.show(myView)`.  Let's say that later, I need that view to be more complex, I can very easily write a Marionette.Layout which displays a bunch of subviews, and just swap that in in place of the old view, and everything just works. The Layout takes care of displaying and closing all of its subviews, which is something that is pretty arduous to deal with in vanilla Backbone.

One of the biggest wins I've got from using Marionette is the ability to very easily render tree structures using the CompositeView, which is influenced by the composite pattern.

As a general point about how it helps creating SPAs, it makes it very easy to compose applications from modules, layouts and views, with each having fewer responsibilities. The low amount of friction experienced when splitting your application up into smaller components makes it far easier to develop, refactor, and test.

I've found that if I ever have a thought that splitting a view into multiple subviews might be a good idea, I should just do it. Marionette makes this easy, and I've never regretted splitting something into smaller views, but I have regretted it when I've chosen not to and normally end up doing it eventually.

Sorry that's not so much about the composite application architecture and more about why Marionette is good.

Answer (score 0):

Q: What is a composite application architecture in JavaScript?

A: Marionette is composite because it is made up of different libraries.  Marionette depends on backbone backbone depends on other libraries as well.  When you put all those libraries together they all help in their own ways.  Backbone can be used without marionette, but when both are used together you should be able to solve the same problems but with less code.

Q: Does AngularJS provide composite application architecture?

A: I don't think so...Because it is not made up of or dependent on other JS libraries.

Q: Why do I need this in JavaScript?

A: Maybe you don't need it.  There are certainly other libraries that can solve the same issues.  You could even use vanilla JavaScript and solve all the same problems yourself.  Marionette is a tool, it makes JavaScript simpler to use.  jQuery makes JavaScript simpler to use as well, but solves a different problem(DOM manipulation).  Backbone solves the problem of how to structure an application in JS, and Marionette reduces the amount of redundant code needed to make an application.  Its all about what is the right tool for the job.